# What do you call "keywords" in R?

Tags: ruby, r

I found Zed Shaw's [Learning Ruby The Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/) very helpful for learning Ruby. I especially found [exercise 37: Symbol Review](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex37.html), which has you research and describe a number of important keywords, symbols etc.

However, now I'm trying to learn R. It seems to me that many of the string escape sequences and operators are actually the same across Ruby and R. However, I have found it difficult to find whatever it is that corresponds to Ruby *keywords* (in Ruby, e.g.: `alias`, `end`, `BEGIN`, `begin`, `break`, etc.) in R.

Hence my question: in R, what corresponds most closely to the category of *things* called *keywords* in Ruby?

Comment: Could you please explain the definition of "keyword"? Possibly the R equivalent could be reserved words (see `?reserved`).

Comment: It’s not terribly useful to learn the reserved words in R.

Comment: @roland. Keywords is the group of Ruby *things* listed as *Keywords* here: http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex37.html

Comment: @KonradRudolph, as a beginner, when reading code, I find it very useful to know which words are user-defined, and which are defined by the language.

Comment: @histelheim Use a syntax highlighter then. But really, the structure of the code in R will be quite obvious without knowing which words are reserved – even more so since R has very few reserved words, those words that are don’t form a logical group, and many things in R are done via built-in (but *non*-reserved) identifiers. If you want to orientate yourself by reserved words you’re misleading yourself.

Comment: @histelheim That's not a definition and thus not useful if you ask for the equivalent in a different language.

Comment: @Roland "The following keywords have special meaning in Ruby and are treated specially by thew Ruby parser: (list).In most languages, these words would be called "reserved words" and they would never be allowed as identifiers. The Ruby parser (...) does not complain if you prefix these keywords with @, @@,$ and use them as instance, class or global variable names. Also, you can use these keywords as method names, with the caveat that the method must always be explicitly invoked through an object.(...)"(The Ruby Programming Language, page 31)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is `Reserved` words.   (Have a look at `?Reserved`)

However, in `R`, almost everything is an object, and most of what one might think of as "keywords" are in fact functions which can be overwritten..  There are very few actual reserved words

```
 if else repeat while function for in next break

 TRUE FALSE NULL Inf NaN NA NA_integer_ NA_real_ NA_complex_ NA_character_
```

---

Edit:  @histelheim regarding your comment about learning the language and reading code, I find it helpful having a solid IDE.   Have a look at Sublime Text with the Enhanced-R package.

Comment: @Roland, not in the usual sense.  For example, you can replace `ifelse` via `ifelse <- function() 3`, but you *cannot* do this with `if`:   `if <- function() 3 #error`

Comment: what is `?Reserved` ?

Comment: @Arup, in `R` you can get help on any function (and more) by preceding it with a question mark `?`.  Thus, on Stackoverflow, when you see someone write `?dnorm` etc, it means, have a look at the help file for that function

Comment: @RicardoSaporta You are right. However, `if` is still linked to `.Primitive("if")`, which is a function.

Comment: Note also that when you overwrite a primitive (not Reserved) function with a non-function you can often still call the function.  E.g. `cat;cat<-"dog";cat("rat");cat". The answer to how this happens has to do with environments plus some built-in magic and is worthy of its own question some day ;-).

Comment: @Roland.  Yes of course, that's why I qualified my comment with "in the usual sense" ;)    After all, even in `C` the if keyword has an underlying function

Comment: @AriB.Friedman, that applies to all functions, so long as you don't overwrite it in the same environment.  ;)   --  The parens are what lets R know to match the function